# Is it possible to port my 64 bit JavaFX App to 32 bit?

Tags: java, javafx, 32bit-64bit, porting, jlink

I have deployed a JavaFX Application using JLink to generate a `.msi` installer.

However, I just now learned that this app won't work on a 32 bit machine, since it's runtime uses Java 14, which is 64 bit. Unfortunately, Oracle stopped releasing 32 bit Java images since Java 9. I really don't want to port my app back to Java 8, since it's a modular project and modules were released in Java 9, besides lots of other stuff I'd have to change.

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: I'm curious where you found a 32-bit machine in the year 2020

Comment: My parents have a 32 bit machine. Unfortunately I didn't find any research on 32 x 64 bit penetration

Comment: Specs? I would think it more likely they have a 32bit jvm than a 32bit machine. I assume you tried installing a 64bit jvm and it gave an error message? What error?